# Calling function in .ts file from html generated by <script>

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I' trying to call a `doThis()` function from my html after it has been generated from a `<script>`.

Because it is a script that runs an external url, I need to add it using a variable in my .ts file. It executes with no problem and creates my html element. That html element is a payment form, when it is completed, it calls a function that is inside the  and gives me the order information as parameter.

My problem here is I'm trying to call a function in my .ts file from that html function to use that order information but I can't find a way to reference that .ts function from inside my html.

**.ts file**

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

    giftupHtml: string = `<script type="text/javascript">
                            (function (g, i, f, t, u, p, s) {
                                g[u] = g[u] || function() { (g[u].q = g[u].q || []).push(arguments) };
                                p = i.createElement(f);
                                p.async = 1;
                                p.src = t;
                                s = i.getElementsByTagName(f)[0];
                                s.parentNode.insertBefore(p, s);
                            })(window, document, 'script', 'https://cdn.giftup.app/dist/gift-up.js', 'giftup');

                            // Track conversions:
                            giftup("conversion", function (payload) { 
                                   doThis();
                            });
                           </script>
                           `;

    constructor( ) { }

    doThis() {
        console.log("This isn't called.");
    }
```

Basically the giftupHtml is used as [innerHTML] inside a .
It renders fine and I know the html function is called since I can console.log(payload) but I can't reference my .ts file or function.

Comment: In your constructor, `window.doThis = this.doThis.bind(this);`

Comment: Says property doThis doesn't exist on type window.
Would window["doThis'] do the trick?

Comment: It means the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Anything you call outside the Angular zone will need to be wrapped in a call from ngZone. And make sure you use arrow functions so that the references to this stay as the component.

```
constructor(ngZone: NgZone) {
  window['doThis'] = () => {
    ngZone.run(() => {
      // Now you have full access to the component here
    });
  };
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  delete window['doThis'];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

actually thats normal you are trying to access angular function from script window you cant do that normally but there is some workarounds 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/call-angular-2-function-from-javascript
but  i am really interested in the reason you are doing this for?

Comment: Thank you for the link !

Comment: I'm integrating a third-party form on the website and I can't access its values since it is an iframe (from another domain). So they call a function when the process is completed to let me access the order's payload. Since we track analytics where I work, we would like to call a function that sends part of that payload to analytics.

Comment: can you accept it as the correct answer -if it helped you- thanks in advance

Comment: It's a fairly new question so I'll wait a little to see if there is a better answer.